# jQGrid - reordering action buttons on sorting rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, jqgrid

How we can rearrange the sort order of action buttons (Edit and Delete) in jQGrid as per sorting of the concern rows?

HTML:

```
<table id="grid"></table>
```

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g27gL/16/)

I have coded different edit button and save buttons in grid.

I will update this post if some one feels hard to understand my query.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using custom format function (**formatter**), which renders buttons. On each button you can set click handler with rowparameters

```
 colModel:[
    {name:'act',index:'act', width:120, sortable:false, formatter: customFormat},
    {name:'emp_name', index:'emp_name', key: true, width:100, editable:true},
    {name:'emp_id', index:'emp_id', width:80, editable:true},
    {name:'addr', index:'addr', width:100, editable:true}
],


function customFormat (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    console.log(rowObject);
    return '<input type="button" class="editbtn" value="edit" onclick="console.log('+rowObject.emp_id+')"/><input type="button" class="delbtn" value="del" onclick="console.log('+rowObject.emp_id+')"/>';
}
```

Knowing which emp_id is clicked, you can call you own custom function which will do somthing with that emp_id

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g27gL/18/)